# SparkFun EL Sequencer does not work

Tags: wires

I have connected to EL wire, 12v EL Inverter to SparkFun EL Sequencer but it does not work (no battery is connected). The connections are the same like in Hookup Guide (https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/3/6/9/ELSequencerHookUp_bb.png). Furthermore, there is no light indicating that it works but I hear a noise/whistle from the Inverter.

Do I have to program the EL Sequencer or does it automatically turn the EL wire on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Sparkfun probably only put the bootloader on the board. The [tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/el-sequencerescudo-dos-hookup-guide) is written in a way that suggests the need to flash the board.

Also the board does not imediatly work with the 12V inverter. If you have the battery you should attach it and see the `PWR` LED turn on.

*The inverter only provides voltage to the EL wire* and **not the Microcontroller**, power to the microcontroller is provided by way of a regulator(`U2`), ***not*** the LM317 the last quote from the one comment shows how you can connect to the 12V inverter.

What you should do instead of having to go the route of all the wiring is to connect both the battery to `BATT IN` and the inverter, but ensuring that the microcontroller is programmed before hand.

> Arduino Code
>
> Once you have all of your hardware hooked up properly, it’s time to
>   program your Sequencer to run the EL Wire display as you want. You
>   will need to download the Arduino code in order to follow along with
>   the example.
>
> You can also download the most up-to-date code from the EL Sequencer
>   [GitHub repository](https://github.com/sparkfun/EL_Sequencer).
>
> We will be working with the “SparkFun_EL_Example.ino” example. If you
>   need a review on how to upload Arduino code to your board or using the
>   Arduino IDE, please check our tutorial [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-arduino-ide). Also, if you are unsure
>   about installing the FTDI drivers, please check out [this tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ftdi-drivers).

Also from one of the [Tech support notes](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/el-sequencerescudo-dos-hookup-guide/discuss):

> Using 12V to Power Both the EL Inverter & Microcontroller
>
> If you are using a 12V wall adapter to power the 12V Inverter, you
>   would still need to provide power to the microcontroller side. One
>   solution with your 12V wall adapter to provide power to the 12V
>   inverter and Atmega328P is to get a barrel jack adapter to 2 pin JST
>   adapter [ https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8734 ], thus connecting
>   the 12V wall adapter to the “BATT IN.” This is assuming that your wall
>   adapter is using a center positive barrel jack.
>
> From there you can connect the 2 pin JST labeled “DC Out” to the 12V
>   inverter’s input voltage. To connect, I recommend using the male DC
>   barrel jack adapter [ https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10287 ] and a
>   2pin JSt jumper wire [ https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8670 or
>   https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8671 ]. You will need to wire strip
>   the cable to be able to connect it to the screw terminals.
>
> Lastly, you would need to add a solder jumper to SJ1 so that you
>   bypass the voltage regulator between your external power (“BATT IN”)
>   to provide power to the inverter’s “DC OUT”. This will provide power
>   to your 12V inverter’s input.

**Warning: if SJ1 is closed, inverter will see 5V with FTDI plugged in and switch at USB**